# Image change between view templates stopping onclick dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I placed an onclick dropdown menu in my top navigation bar. In the top navigation bar, I wanted to change this image in my **new.html.erb** view template:

```
<li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="create"> <%= link_to image_tag("createpost.svg"),new_post_url, method: :get %> </span> </li>
```

I copied the entire navigation bar code from **application.html.erb** & added it to the top of **new.html.erb**, changing *createpost.svg* to *createone.svg* :

```
<li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="create"> <%= link_to image_tag("createone.svg"),new_post_url, method: :get %> </span> </li>
```

However, although the image changed, the onclick dropdown menu is no longer working in my **new.html.erb** view template..

Tried many solutions & can't figure this out. Any help would be amazing - thank you!!

**application.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

<ul class="navigation-bar">

 <div class="navigation-bar-right-inset">
   <li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="create"> <%= link_to image_tag("createpost.svg"),new_post_url, method: :get %> </span> </li> 
   <li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="home"> <%= link_to image_tag("home.svg"), posts_url, data: {no_turbolink: true} %> </span> </li>
    <li class="navigation-bar-right" id="drop"> <span class="settings"> <a href="#"> <img class="#" src="/assets/settings.svg"> </a> </span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li> <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path, method: :get %> </li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_url, method: :delete %> </li>   
      </ul>
    </li>
 </div>

</ul>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>

<ul class="navigation-bar">

 <div class="navigation-bar-right-inset">
   <li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="create"> <%= link_to image_tag("createone.svg"),new_post_url, method: :get %> </span> </li> 
   <li class="navigation-bar-right"> <span class="home"> <%= link_to image_tag("home.svg"), posts_url, data: {no_turbolink: true} %> </span> </li>
    <li class="navigation-bar-right" id="drop"> <span class="settings"> <a href="#"> <img class="#" src="/assets/settings.svg"> </a> </span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li> <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_registration_path, method: :get %> </li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_url, method: :delete %> </li>   
      </ul>
    </li>
 </div>

</ul>
```

**posts.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
$("#drop").click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).find(".dropdown").fadeToggle "fast"

$(document).on "click", (e) ->
  $trigger = undefined
  $trigger = $("#drop")
  $(".dropdown").fadeOut "fast"  if $trigger isnt e.target and not $trigger.has(e.target).length
```

**CSS**

```
ul li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:100; 
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: helvetica;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
$(document).on "click", "#drop", (e) ->
  $trigger = $(this)
  $(".dropdown").fadeOut "fast"  if $trigger isnt e.target and not $trigger.has(e.target).length
```

1. Always make sure you're referencing a valid `DOM` element (esp when delegating)
2. You're referencing `posts.js.coffee` -- are you sure this is called in `new.html.erb`?

Comment: Hi Richard - thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. I placed an alert(); box in the coffee script code and it was called in the new.html.erb view. :/

Comment: Boo hoo, let's cry about it a little more. What debugging have you done? Any errors in your console? How are you referencing your `posts.js.coffee`?

Comment: Just managed to make out your comment through the tears. No errors in the console & referencing with `//= require_tree .` in `application.js.`